# Are the "h" in pinyin always pronounced as "[x]" in IPA?

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation, spoken, ipa

Chinese (Mandarin) use [x] to pronounce *h* sound. [It does not have any sounds such as [h] and [ɸ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Mandarin).

However, I'm not sure if it is fine to assume that all the *h* in pinyin are pronounced as [x]. According to [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/pinyin-h-sound-pronounciation) and the answer, [x] is the standard sound, but is there any case to use a different sound on the *h* in pinyin? If so, how can I know if it is pronounced as such, given that [it is generally impossible to know which IPA sound is used in Chinese words](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17813/are-there-any-online-dictionaries-that-supply-ipa-transcriptions-for-mandarin)?

Comment: Being pedantic, but I assume you are excluding sh-, ch-, zh- from your considerations, aren't you?

Comment: @Michaelyus Ah, I got what you are meaning. Yes, I excluded them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pinyin "h" sound, pronounciation](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/pinyin-h-sound-pronounciation)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, h = [x] (also ㄏ in bopomofo).

---

Wikipedia has an entire chart entitled [Help:IPA/Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Mandarin) that lists consonants:

> [image]

and vowels

> [image]

---

Many old dictionaries, especially topolectical dictionaries, used IPA or a simplified version of IPA.

Consider [Li Rong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Rong_(linguist))'s (李荣) edited [Great Dictionary of Modern Chinese Dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Dictionary_of_Modern_Chinese_Dialects) (现代汉语方言大词典). Here's an example from《哈尔滨方言词典》:

> [image]

Here you can clearly see 火 is:

> xuo

You can also see that the other terms are also written using IPA, albeit slightly simplified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I saw the exact Wikipedia page. But I wonder if the chart is what is only generally applicable and has some exceptions, or can be applied to ALL words.

Comment: @Blaszard Yes they all generally stay the same. Otherwise you would see fluctuation in bopomofo and in pinyin. The only exceptions, would be exactly that: exceptions. For instance we get questions like: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/26801/4136 where the pronunciations of characters like 儿 and 二 are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Standard pronunciation is indeed [x], but it can vary regionally [h ~ x].

Note, Standard Chinese *does* contain [h] in some monosyllabic filler words:

> SC has three syllabic nasals, [m], [n], and [ŋ], which mostly occur in interjections, such as [hm] (showing contempt), [hŋ] (showing contempt), [m] (‘yes’),
> [n] (‘yes’), and [ŋ] (‘yes’). Although such words have a somewhat marginal
> status, they have been included in some dictionaries, such as Xiandai Hanyu
> Cidian (Chinese Academy of Social Sciences Institute of Linguistics 1978).

- *Phonology of Standard Chinese,* 2.9 Syllabic Consonants

Comment: Has a character ever been assigned to [hm]? I have seen appropriate glyphs for the others but [hm] seems a little harder. Edit: found it - 噷.

Comment: @Mou某 [噷](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%99%B7#Chinese)